# JS/TypeScript Generate times between hours

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So let's say we have two times:

> 7:30 - 12:00

So my question is how can I generate an array with times like this:

> 7:30, 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30

I need this for a booking, so let's say the business will open at 7:30 and every booking that you can make will be 30 min(this time can change, could be one hour or more)

Whats the best way to generate something like this in JS?

Comment: You can View this Example https://jsfiddle.net/m1ruw1x6/35/ I wish help you to solve problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment in the code says, you can remove the 0 before the hours if you don't want it, by removing that line.

If you don't want the end in the array just replace the `<=` by `<`in the for loop

```js
function timeArray(start, end){
    var start = start.split(":");
    var end = end.split(":");

    start = parseInt(start[0]) * 60 + parseInt(start[1]);
    end = parseInt(end[0]) * 60 + parseInt(end[1]);

    var result = [];

    for ( time = start; time <= end; time+=30){
        result.push( timeString(time));
    }
 
    return result;
}

function timeString(time){
    var hours = Math.floor(time / 60);
    var minutes = time % 60;

    if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours; //optional
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;

    return hours + ":" + minutes;
}

console.log(timeArray("7:30", "12:00"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Little verbose utility, you can use it..

```
var getTimeIntervals = function (time1, time2, slotInMinutes, workingHourStart, workingHourEnd) {
    time1.setMinutes(0); time1.setSeconds(0);
    var arr = [];
    var workingHoursStart = workingHourStart;
    var workingHourEnds = workingHourEnd;
    var workingHourStartFloat = parseFloat("7:30");
    var workingHourEndFloat = parseFloat("12:00");
    while(time1 < time2){
      var generatedSlot = time1.toTimeString().substring(0,5);
      var generatedSlotFloat = parseFloat(generatedSlot);

      time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + slotInMinutes);
      if(generatedSlotFloat >= workingHourStartFloat && generatedSlotFloat < workingHourEndFloat){
          var generatedObject = {
            slot: time1.toTimeString().substring(0,5),
            timeStamp: new Date(time1.getTime())
          };
          arr.push(generatedObject);
      }
    }
   return arr;
 }

var today = new Date();
var tomrorow = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()+1);

console.log(getTimeIntervals(today, tomorrow, 30, "7:30", "12:00"));
```

Function `getTimeIntervals` expects `startDate`, `endDate`, `slotDurationInMinutes`, `workingHoursStart` and `workingHourEnd`.

Why I am returning object is because you may need the timestamp of selected slot in your further application use.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/t8ezfj2q/

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version:

```
timeArray = [];
....
let i = 0;
let hour = 8;
let odd: boolean;
do {
  odd = false;
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    odd = true;
    hour--;
  }
  this.timeArray.push(hour.toString() + (odd ? ":30" : ":00"));
  i++;
  hour++;
} while (i < 12);
....
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-youcjv)